# Reset wp_usermeta in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using multisites, I am trying to reset `wp_usermeta` in phpmyadmin.
I use:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM `wp_users`);
```

but for some reason I am unable to reset the users ID's.

My goal is to get a brand new database in terms of users and users ID's. Website is still in the development phase.

Thanks